Why is Germany looking to import workers from Kenya, specifically?
CNN reports that (according to Kenyan authorities) Berlin agreed to give working permits to "up to" 250,000 "skilled and semi-skilled Kenyan workers".
Why Kenya, specifically?
(N.B. The piece does mention that "The German Interior Ministry adds that it is in confidential talks with several other countries regarding migration agreements." However this isn't terribly clear what it means. As CNN relates it though, the German ministry was more keen to emphasize that the deal [with Kenya] will also allow Germany to "consistently enforce the repatriation of people without a right to remain".)

A few remarks that amend o.m.'s good answer.

The number of up to 250.000 workers that Kenyan President Ruto named has been disclaimed. According to the German Ministry of Interior

Das Migrationsabkommen zwischen Deutschland und Kenia enthält keinerlei Zahlen oder Kontingente von Fachkräften aus Kenia, die in Deutschland arbeiten könnten. Alle Bewerber müssen die Kriterien des Fachkräfteeinwanderungsgesetzes erfüllen.


The migration agreement between Germany and Kenya does not contain any numbers or quotas of skilled workers from Kenya who could work in Germany. All applicants must fulfil the criteria of the Skilled Immigration Act.


Since 2023, the German Federal government has installed a Sonderbevollmächtigter für Migrationsabkommen (Special Commissioner for Migration Agreements) in the Ministry of Interior (BMI). The BMI lists the current migration agreements here.

In June 2024, the comissioner had to answer some questions about his work by members of parliament of the Left party. The strategic thoughts behind his work are probably along the lines of an advisory paper the Stiftung Wissenschaft und Politik published last year.

The text of the Kenya agreement seems not to be available to the public. The most detailed (well, least obscure) first party report of its content is probably this press release by the BMI.


I confess that I was unable to navigate the pages of the Kenyan government. The best I could find was a notice by the African Union Development Agency that at least named who is negotiating on the Kenyan side: the State Department for Diaspora Affairs

Germany is not looking at Kenya specifically. Germany is signing treaties on labor migration with many different countries. Migration treaties exist or are being negotiated with Brazil, Colombia, Ghana, India, Moldova, Morocco, Uzbekistan, and Vietnam. The goal is twofold:

Make up for the "demographic problem" (not enough children for a stable population) with controlled, structured immigration. Skilled workers who come in having a job lined up, perhaps having learned the language, etc.
Reward and encourage countries which try to restrict the uncontrolled, unstructured migration of their citizens and others passing through.
Many countries in the 'Global South' are heavily dependent on remittances from their expatriates. This gives them an enticement to delay the repatriation of their citizens when a country in the 'Global North' wants to deport them. So the deal is that these countries take back undocumented immigrants and send documented immigrants instead.

A significant number of legal immigrants come from other EU countries, which requires no permits.

Seem related to last year's reforms too, which put more emphasis on non-EU workers being given a chance https://www.dw.com/en/german-parliament-reforms-skilled-work-immigration-law/a-66010566

Not restrict migration, but facilitate deportations of "irregular entrants" back to Kenia. See the news release by Olaf Scholz: "Die beiden Staaten haben ein Migrationsabkommen vereinbart, das das Anwerben von Fachkräften erleichtern soll, aber auch die Rückführung irregulär Eingereister. "

@ccprog, one of the key problems with German (and EU) migration policy is that it is traffickers and not visa officials who select who gets in. The treaty is trying to reduce that.

@o.m. That might be the general case, but according to that press release fighting trafficking it is not part of the agreement, only a deportation regime. There are seveal instances in the transcript of the press conference where Scholz very specifically refers this.

@ccprog, Scholz said "Bisher scheint es so zu sein, dass es sich um eine Fluchtbewegung handelt, die sich unmittelbar auf die Region und die Nachbarländer bezieht und nicht darüber hinaus geht. Aber das darf uns nicht dazu verführen, die Sache nicht so ernst zu nehmen, wie sie ist." I'd conclude that they are worried about irregular migration through Kenia. The connection between irregular migration and human trafficking was not emphasized, but I think organized crime is part and parcel of refugee movements to Europe.

Would these skilled Kenyans be temporary GastArbeiters, expected to head back home after some time?  Or would they be able to acquire full residency rights?

@ItalianPhilosopher, most of the Gastarbeiter generation have permanent residency but not citizenship, because until the most recent reforms they would have had to abandon their old citizenship for naturalization in Germany. With employment, immigrants can apply for German citizenship after five years of temporary residency. There would be language tests, etc.

Ah I searched in the wrong department. The "Migrationsabkommen" are under the oversight of the Ministry of Interior, and there is a dedicated web page.

@o.m. That answers the question well enough, but note that dual nationalities allowances are, in many circumstances, not always a "right". Even elsewhere than Germany's:  expecting new citizens to forego their old nationality doesn't disallow immigration by itself.

@ccprog, that page has the usual political buzzwords. Of course they want to respect refugees' rights while they seek for ways to deport them faster ...

@ItalianPhilosopher, the point is that, for decades, one of the main obstacles on the way to German citizenship for Turkish residents was making that tradeoff -- Turkish citizenship and German permanent residency vs. German citizenship and no Turkish citizenship. For Italians and Greeks, the rules and tradeoffs were different.

@o.m. Fair enough.  I did not realize dual nationalities had different rules for different groups (but I did know Turks have historically been critical of GastArbeiter arrangements)

@ItalianPhilosopher, historically Germany was against dual nationalities. But for EU citizens that rule was weakened sooner than for others.

Are there estimates how many Kenyans are staying illegally in Germany? The country is not the closest to Germany, do probably less than 250k. The benefit of being able to send illegal immigrants back might be less important than the economic benefit of additional labor.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Staying illegal is less of a phenomenon than elsewhere. Mostly, it is the better strategy to throw your passport away and register as an asylum seeker. This way you not only get a basic health insurance, but as long as you can obscure your identity, even if the asylum is denied, the state has nowhere to send you back to. That is why it is so important for the German government that Kenya accepts identification by biometric attributes in the agreement.

@ccprog Sure, but given the long distance of Kenya to Germany, illegal immigration from Kenya is probably not the major bulk of unregistered/illegal immigrants in Germany and probably much less than 250k. Therefore I think that economic considerations might have played an even bigger role.

@Schmuddi, fixed.

@ccprog "Not restrict migration, but facilitate deportations of "irregular entrants" back to Kenia." uhm, that is very clearly and explicitly restricting de-facto migration.
